# Что делать если вылезает ошибка c owm?

Tags: python, pyowm

Написал код, который будет показывать погоду, но вылезает ошибка.

сам код

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM('8a50c...79960', language = "ru")
place = input("в каком городе?: ")

observation = own.weather_at_place('place')
w = observation.get_weather()

temp = w.get_temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print("в городе" + place + "сейчас" + w.get_detailed_status())
print("температура сейчас в районе" + str(temp))

if temp < 10:
    print("сейчас ужасно холодно, укутайся в одеяло и выпей чайку)")
elif temp <20:
    print("холодновато, выйти в шортах и футболке будет плохой идеей")
else:
    print("ну и жарище,может по мороженому?")
```

а вот ошибка

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\python\test.py", line 3, in 
> owm = pyowm.OWM('8a50c...9960', language = "ru")
> AttributeError: module 'pyowm' has no attribute 'OWM'

Comment: Возможно у вас в папке с файлом test.py лежит файл pyowm.py, в котором нет класса OWM.

Comment: Примеры устаревшие и все на них лезут. Сейчас все запросы к разным API идут через соответствующие менеджеры. Научитесь уже пользоваться поиском. [ПРИМЕР ИЗ ИСПОЛЬЗУЕМОЙ ВАМИ БИБЛИОТЕКИ](https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm#example)

Answer (score 1):

В python для отлова ошибок и исключений используется конструкция `try/except`. В блок `try` вы вставляете проблемный кусок кода, в котором может случиться ошибка. Если ошибки не случается, то выполнение кода идёт дальше. Если же произошла ошибка, то выполняется код, который помещён в блок `except`. Также помимо `except` есть ещё `else` и `finally`. Про них, я думаю, вы почитаете сами, если интересно. Вашу проблему можно решить так:

```
try:
    owm = pyowm.OWM('8a50c...79960', language = "ru")
except:
    print('Произошла ошибка') # Можно сделать что-то более полезное
```

Comment: я ничего не понял можешь доступным языком я прост новичек

Comment: @ThomasShelby поправил ответ

Comment: @Elusha, если в модуле нет класса OWM, то исключение будет вылетать всегда (я думаю вряд ли будет такая ситуация, что класс то появится в модуле, то исчезнет), и обработка исключения никак не поможет.

Comment: @insolor вопрос "Что делать если ВЫЛЕЗАЕТ ОШИБКА с owm". Да и вообще не нравится мой ответ - не обращайте внимания, напишите свой, если очень не нравится, то так уж и быть поставьте мне минус

Comment: @Elusha, подавить исключение - не решение проблемы из вопроса. Это все равно что просто удалить код, на котором возникает ошибка - ошибка конечно исчезнет, но работать все равно ничего не будет. Вопрос не в том что нравится или не нравится, а в том что является решением или не является решением. Если есть претензии к моим комментариям и/или вам кажется что я каким-то образом лично вас оскорбляю - поставьте на комментарии флаг, придет модератор и во всем разберется.